# Clicking on hidden radio button not working in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I used radio button with the following styles in a `div` (for selecting it by clicking on `div`):

```
.plans-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 0;

  .plan {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    position: relative;

    &:hover {
      ::ng-deep .card {
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
          0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
      }
    }

    &__type {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="plans-list">
        <div class="plan" *ngFor="let plan of planTypes">
            <input (click)="calculateTotal()" class="plan__type" type="radio" name="planType" [value]="plan.value"
                formControlName="planType" #planType>
            <app-plan-item [type]="plan.title" [active]="planType.checked" [params]="planParameters">
            </app-plan-item>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Clicking on the radio button not working and `active` class will not assign to the `app-plan-item` element! What is wrong?

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahw2bf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Can u create stackblitz

Comment: @Çağrı Ok sure.

Comment: @Çağrı https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahw2bf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: The checkbox is not reacting to the event because of "visibility: hidden". For Example with opacity: 0 it will trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change css visibility to opacity
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5v457f

```
.plan__type {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity:0; 
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```